# Why the "service --status-all | grep mysql" get many unrelated result?

Tags: command-line, services, grep

It seems weird here while running

```
service --status-all | grep mysql
```

why I get so many wrong result?

It works fine on Centos where i am getting:

```
mysql is running xxxxxxx
```

This is what i am getting on Ubuntu:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`service --status-all` shows its output on both STDOUT (file descriptor 1) and STDERR (file descriptor 2), with the services for which the status can be determined on STDOUT (indicated by `[+]` or `[-]`) and the services whose status can not be determined on STDERR (indicated by `[?]`).

While doing `service --status-all | grep mysql`, you are running `grep` over only the STDOUT of `service --status-all`, that's why everything showing on STDERR are being shown (along with the possible output of `grep`).

To get only the desired result, redirect both run redirect both STDOUT and STDERR to `grep`:

```
service --status-all |& grep mysql
```

**Test:**

Look at the signs inside `[]`:

```
% service --status-all >/dev/null  ## Discarding STDOUT
 [ ? ]  apport
 [ ? ]  binfmt-support
 [ ? ]  console-setup
 [ ? ]  dns-clean
 [ ? ]  irqbalance
 [ ? ]  killprocs
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ ? ]  lightdm
 [ ? ]  mysql


% service --status-all 2>/dev/null  ## Discarding STDERR
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ - ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  atd
 [ + ]  atop
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  brltty
 [ + ]  cron
```

Comment: Amazing Answer tnx a lot .

Comment: One more question, how do you know  `service --status-all shows its output on both STDOUT (file descriptor 1) and STDERR (file descriptor 2)`. I can't get a clue in the `manual` (man service)

Comment: @lizhe Yeah, the `man` page does not contain this..you need to either check it yourself or check the source code..it's kind of intuitive you see :)

Comment: You help me a lot, Tnx. :）