# service --status-all | grep <anything> always returns [ ? ] entries

Tags: services, grep

Trying to get the state of a service that is running (or not).  I use `service --status-all | grep <service>` and no matter what I enter for `<service>`, I always get:

`[ + ]  <service I grepped>
 [ ? ]  rng-tools`

Any ideas on why I am getting `[ ? ] rng-tools` in the result?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? perhaps this is still relevant [Why the “service --status-all | grep mysql” get many unrelated result?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720141/why-the-service-status-all-grep-mysql-get-many-unrelated-result)

Comment: It was and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Link above gave me the answer.

`service --status-all |& grep <service>`